# One model multiple "origins"

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model design issue.

Models User, Patient, Doctor, Nurse can write Note(s). They all have a foreign key to Note. What I'd like is to add a field to Note so I know from what type of model the Note comes from. In SQL I could write something like

```
SELECT * FROM notes WHERE origin='nurse'
```

Do I have to add a field as CharField and I assign the referred model string name or there is a field type more specific for what I want to do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what the [ContentType model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) is for.

```
class Note(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now you can do:

```
ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Nurse)
```